# How to send messages to IoT Gateway with server running on Google Linux instance

Tags: google-cloud-iot

I am trying to send messages from my mac to a Google IoT Gateway running on a Google VM linux instance. Can't get the gateway server running in the linux instance to ack messages sent from scripts on my mac.

Set up Google VM linux instance and followed directions in:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-iot-core-gateways/index.html#0

I did try to read through https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-iot-gateways-rpi.
I setup `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT` to point to my project.

I updated the `ADDR` in the `thermostat.py` script to point to the address of the linux instance. But I am not quite sure which address to use.
The address obtained by running ifconfig on the linux instance isn't pingable from my mac. I used the static address assigned to the linux instance, and although I can ping that, I don't see the server running on the gateway ack the message send by the script.

On the linux instance I run the gateway server, and if I run `thermostat.py` on the same instance, I see the messages received by the gateway and the Google IoT console.

However I am having trouble running `thermostat.py` from my local machine (mac). I want to get this working before trying it on my embedded device. I can see the script attempt to send the message but I don't see any messages received on the server.

Which ip address should I be using to communicate with the gateway server on my linux instance ?

Other than setting the `ADDR` and `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`, are there any other changes I need to make to `thermostat.py`?

Comment: Hey Sajid, to back up a second, what are you trying to do specifically? Running a gateway in a VM isn't really what that feature is used for. It's designed to have a more powerful machine locally being able to communicate as a proxy for lesser powered machines on the edge that might not be able to communicate over the internet.

If you could give some context of what you're trying to do, there might be an easier way than the gateway feature.

Answer (score 0):

The VMs in GCE (Google Compute Engine) have a locked down firewall by default. You need to open up the ports for the HTTP connection so the traffic to the gateway can get through.